# Whats the purpose of this behind an URL "/?v1="

Tags: http, web, url, hyperlink

What is the purpose of /?v1= to put behind an URL to made it work in a game client.exe?

If i don't put this /?v1= it will not show the webpage inside the game client.

It supposed to be a URL that the game link within the game to show a cash shop.

For example

http://yourcashshopurl.com/cashshop.php <--- will not show anything inside game
http://yourcashshopurl.com/cashshop.php/?v1= <----- then this will show the page inside game

So, what is the purpose of /?v1= ???

thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic answer to this. The meaning of any query parameter depends on the actual application. So what `?v1=` means depends on what the developers of this website decided it should mean.